# Can't select widget

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, app-widgets

I have an android 5.1.1 tablet. There is a narrow, tall widget appearing at the top left, and just says "Problem loading widget". Whenever I hold it for several seconds, it just acts like I am holding an empty space. I can't select it. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: What tablet?  When did this start happening?

Comment: App related to the widget might be uninstalled. Try clearing the data and cache of the home screen launcher currently in use.